# How to remove HTML tag (not a specific tag ) with content from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, typescript

Is there any way to  strip HMTL tag with content  in HTML

example :

```
const regexForStripHTML = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi
const text = "OCEP <sup>&reg;</sup> water product"
const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '')

output : 'OCEP &reg; water product'
```

I need to remove `&reg;` also from a string

expected output
`OCEP water product`

Comment: Did you mean to type `const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '')` ? That might be the issue for replacing the HTML tags.

Comment: @phentnil updated to const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '')

Comment: do you need it with any html tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all HTML tags and the innerText can be done with the following snippet. The Regexp captures the opening tag's name, then matches all content between the opening and closing tags, then uses the captured tag name to match the closing tag.

```js
const regexForStripHTML = /<([^</> ]+)[^<>]*?>[^<>]*?<\/\1> */gi;
const text = "OCEP <sup>&reg;</sup> water product";
const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '');
console.log(text);
console.log(stripContent);
```

Comment: the term &reg; will dynamic , it may have any content

Comment: So, a regex like `&[^&;]*?;` for any HTML entities? I can update my answer with that if that's what you mean.

Comment: Or do you mean you want to remove HTML tags and any content in between the opening and closing tags?

Comment: yes,need to remove HTML tags with any content

Comment: Just updated the code. Let me know if there are cases where it fails, but it should be resilient for nested HTML tags, too.

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice your use-case:

```js
const regexForStripHTML = /<sup.*>.*?<\/sup>/ig
const text = "OCEP <sup>&reg;</sup> water product"
const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '');

console.log(stripContent);
```

If you want to do it with any HTML tag. See code below:

```js
const regexForStripHTML = /<.*>.*?/ig
const text = "OCEP <html>&reg;</html> water product"
const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '');

console.log(stripContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Context

To remove the text from between the tags you would need to match opening and closing tags of the same tag name. This regex would match the starting tags `<(?<tagname>.*?)>`. Notice how `tagname` remembers the and is being used for the regex part of the corresponding closing tags which is `<\/\k<tagname>>` the part in between `.*?` is to match for any text.

### Code

```js
const regexForStripHTML = /(<(?<tagname>.*?)>.*?<\/\k<tagname>>)/g
const text = "OCEP <sup>&reg;</sup> water product"
const stripContent = text.replaceAll(regexForStripHTML, '$')
```

### Note

I haven't thought about what happens if the tags are nested.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JQuery there is a sweet elegant way of doing it:

```
var res = $('<div>').append(text).text();
```

The created *<div>* ensures correct result in case that the text is already stripped

Comment: I don't see the "jQuery" tag in the OP's question. Do you?